# Signing Windows Electron App

Tags: electron

I have an Electron app that compiles fine on Windows using `npm run ewin`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js",
    "pack": "build",
    "ewin": "build --win --ia32 --x64",
    "ewinsign": "export CSC_LINK=file:///${HOME}/certificates/certificate.pfx; export CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=\"$( cat ${HOME}/certificates/certificates_pw.txt )\"; npm run clean:win && build --win --ia32 --x64",
  },
```

So I added the `ewinsign` in an attempt to get it to sign the app.

I based `ewinsign` on this discussion:
https://discuss.atom.io/t/signing-windows-app-installer/32511

`ewinsign` fails with this error:

```
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I did not really expect it to work because I am running my build on Windows, and bash commands are not typically available on Windows.

Signing Windows apps should be something with a well known solution so I am hesitant to start hacking together my own solution.

In summary:

1. I am building my app on Windows.
2. I have my certificate located here: `${HOME}/certificates/certificate.pfx`
3. I have a file with the password located here: `${HOME}/certificates/certificate_pw.txt`
4. I can successfully build unsigned with `npm run ewin`.

How can I add a `ewinsign` command that will build a signed Windows app?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a bat script wrapper that sets the environment variables.  That was easier to debug because I could add `env` statement to see what the environment variables were set to.

Here is the script:

```
set CSC_LINK=file://%USERPROFILE%/certificates/certificate.pfx

set /p CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=<"%USERPROFILE%/certificates/certificates_pw.txt"

npm run ewin
```

Of particular note is the `=<` batch syntax to read a file into a variable.  and the `/p` syntax to only read one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use that command and try with the windows replacements, you would be looking for the following:

1. `set` is the command that you would use to create a windows
   environment variable (instead of export)
2. `type` is the equivalent of the bash 'cat' for
       windows.
3. What is {HOME} for you? Is that in your "C:\Users\"Your
           User Name" directory? If so, you could use
           `%USERPROFILE%` to get that value.

The resulting code would look something like this:

`"ewinsign": "set CSC_LINK=file:///%USERPROFILE%/certificates/certificate.pfx; set CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=\"$( type %USERPROFILE%/certificates/certificates_pw.txt )\"; npm run clean:win && build --win --ia32 --x64"`

However, I haven't tested that code, so I am not sure if it will work or not.

Now, I haven't code signed with electron-builder, but I would assume that you would use the [windows build options](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#WinBuildOptions) to enforce a certificate. This would be setup in the "build" section of your package.json file:

```
"build":{
    "appid":"yourid",
    "asar": true,
    "forceCodeSigning": true,
    "win":{
        "target": "...",
        "publisherName": "..."
        "certificateFile": "...",
        "certificatePassword":"...",
        "certificateSubjectName":"...",
        "certificateSha1":"...",
        "signingHashAlgorithms":"..."
    }

}
```

You might have to play around with those values to get something working, but based on the documentation, that is how I would do it. Reference the parent options [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options)